# auth/calendar scope doesn't show in OAuth Consent scopes list (yet users are asked to grant access to Calendar)

Tags: oauth, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

It's completely possible I've misunderstood the situation with scopes and Google's OAuth Consent...but I'm seeing something quite unusual. I'm using Google Calendar API v3 with OAuth2 to gain access to users' Calendar data. However, when I look into the OAuth Consent settings in the Google Developer console for the project I don't see any calendar-related scopes, yet the user is asked for the correct scopes to be granted.

[image: What I'd Expect To See]

[image: What I Actually See]

My expectation is that without the auth/calendar (or other calendar-related scopes) there's no way for the customer to be shown the scopes during they OAuth Consent screen?

Comment: On thin ice here because I was actually unaware that the OAuth Consent Screen (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent) includes a set of project-wide Scopes. When I've used Google services w/ Scopes, I've only ever defined the Scopes in code and not at the project-level. Are you defining the richer set of Scopes in your application?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  The scopes requested fro m the user are in your code all dev console does is validate which ones you are allowed to use in your code

Answer (score 0):

The scopes granted to the application are for the service account, now when the users are using your application they need to allow it to access their Google accounts unless you are using [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth#perform-g-suite-domain-wide-delegation-of-authority)